# Need to extract background for Image Annotation

Tags: java, python, scikit-learn

I have Mask Images as follows,

[image: Image Segmentation Mask]

Now I have already extracted the white area which is the object location using OpenCv contours method but I also need to find the black area as Polygon or MultiPolygon and I also want to extract it. My only constraint is that solution must be fast enough as I have a lot of such images.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can find the corners of the white box than it means you just need to add the other 4 corners of the image to get black region

Let's say your image 800x600

(0,0) (0,600) (800,0) (800,600) + contours coordinates

Comment: I can have multiple objects as well, would simply adding their coodinates would work in that case as well?